# Converting a SavedModel to TFLite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've downloaded a FasterRCNN SavedModel from [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz). I'd like to convert it to a TFLite model. This seems like something simple to do with the [tflite_convert cli](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline).

```
tflite_convert --output_file model.tflite --saved_model_dir faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2018_01_28/saved_model
```

However, I'm receiving some issues regarding the input dimensions not being specified

```
ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'image_tensor' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'
```

Does anyone know a way around this? If it's not possible to use arbitrarily sized images in TFLite, I'm guessing there must be a away to overwrite image_tensor dimensions.

Comment: As the error suggests, you'll need a fixed dimension for your image size. You can't change the input shape of a tensor belonging to a frozen graph. You can try to retrain a FasterRCNN on your dataset thereby specifying the input shape for the model.

Comment: So the only way around this is to retrain the model? There's not a way to load the SavedModel or frozen graph and specify the dimensions of image_tensor?

Comment: I have personally tried modifying the input tensor for a frozen graph but no modifications can be made once the graph is freezed.

Comment: @BadProgrammer Are you able to convert faster rcnn model to .tflite ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code snippet to do that.

```
saved_model_dir = 'Path_to_saved_model_dir'

# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the TF Lite model.
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

NOTE: This function doesn't allow you to specify the input shape, so to do that you can use `from_concrete_functions`

```
model = tf.saved_model.load(saved_model_dir)
concrete_func = model.signatures[
  tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
concrete_func.inputs[0].set_shape([1, 256, 256, 3])
converter = TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Dhairya...it is a very good solution.